# How do I create sequential numbers across records in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I have two tables, `foo` and `bar`:

```
foo
,----------------.
|id | name | ... |
|---+------+-----|
| 1 | abc  | ... |
| 2 | xyz  | ... |
| ...            |
`----------------'

bar
,-------------------------.
| id | foo_id | num | ... |
|----+--------+-----+-----|
| 1  | 1      | 1   | ... |
| 2  | 1      | 2   | ... |
| 3  | 1      | 3   | ... |
| 4  | 2      | 1   | ... |
| 5  | 2      | 2   | ... |
| ...                     |
`-------------------------'
```

For each `foo` record, there are many `bar` records, each with a slot number (`num`), which should be a value from 1 - N for each `foo_id`.  Thus, there's a unique key on (`foo_id`, `num`).  These slot numbers are meaningful, and must be sequential.

Because of that last constraint, I can't use Oracle's native sequences (as they aren't guaranteed to be sequential, and don't seem to be meant for values that are meaningful).  The number of `foo` records is also *extermely* large, and having a sequence for each `foo_id` seems highly impractical anyway.

So, my question is - what approaches exist for creating these numbers on insertion that would hold up under high concurrency?  Is my only option to lock and select `MAX(num) + 1`, and release the lock on commit?

Comment: How does that "must be sequential" part work if a record gets deleted?

Answer (score 2):

you can use a 2 step aproach:

1. you can put your records into database concurrenly using sequence
2. run a script that will populate num out of sequence numbers:

   ```
   --q1
   insert into bar (id, foo_id, seq_num) values (:id, :foo, someseq.next_val)

   --q2
   update bar b1 set
   num = (select 1+count(*) from bar b2 
   where b2.foo_id = b1._foo_id 
   and b2.seq_num < b1.seq_num)
   where num is null
   ```

Or you could have bar with gaps, but then have a view bar_vw that would be correcting it on a fly:

```
     create view bar_vw as
        select id, foo_id, 
        row_number() over (partition by foo_id, order by seq_num) as num 
     from bar
```

Comment: I really like the second solution because it keeps track of what you really care about (which is insert order) using a sequence, but translates that into an ordinal number for business/application use. However, it all depends on how the user wants to handle DELETEs. The first answer will fail in the presence of DELETE by the way so it can't be used at all in that case, whereas the second will "cover up" deletes by shifting the sequence. We can change the first answer from 1+count(*) into 1+nvl(max(num),0) if we want to handle deletes without filling in gaps.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a way to architect the system such that only one session at a time is inserting `bar` rows for any particular `foo` row, that would be ideal since that would eliminate actual contention (I assume you'd still want to code to handle it just in case).

To manage concurrency, you'd almost certainly need to lock the parent `foo` row (`select for update`) and then do the `max(num) + 1` from the `bar` rows with that `foo_id`.  I suppose you could potentially omit the step of locking the `foo` record and create a materialized view that does a fast refresh on commit to validate that the `num` values are sequential but it seems highly unlikely that this would be faster and it seems highly likely that it would make the code more complex since you're now catching exceptions at commit time rather than simply blocking until you can move forward.